# Trouble with adding default subfolder with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

I have next rewire rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)example\.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(pl|no|en) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/en/ [R=301,L]
```

and expected that if url didn't have subfolder pl no or en It would added en subfolder.
But on my ubuntu server I get url like this:
http://example.com/enenenenenenenenenenenenenenenenenenen/index.php

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a slash after the `^`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)example\.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(pl|no|en) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/en/ [R=301,L]
```

The REQUEST_URI usually begins with a `/`

Comment: seems better, but example.com/test still rewrites to some strange example.com/en/index.php not example.com/en/test